# Join two mysql columns and display distinct values while sorting from third column

Tags: mysql, sorting, distinct

I've created a basic chat program on my website and I would like to display the 10 visible people in the chat, to those that you have corresponded with most recently first. I am continuously failing to see the correct results and believe I can not use a UNION for this.

So what I want to do is look in both the user_id, and recipient, columns WHERE I am either the recipient of a message or the sender. This will produce a list of users that I have corresponded with. The problem is I want this list of user_ids sorted by msg_id DESCENDING or by `date` DESCENDING, whichever. However all of the queries that I have tried are either giving me the user_ids that I want, but sorting by user_ids, or else sorting properly but not providing a DISTINCT user_id, so they would be listed in my chat several times. Basically the chat bar shows 10 people, and since you may have many more friends than that on the website, I would like to show the users you most recently corresponded with as it makes no sense for you to send someone a chat message, close the window, and in order to send them another msg you would have to navigate back to their profile to open the chat. The 10 quick friends thumbnails I think would work best if showing contacts you most recently either sent a message to or received one from.

```
CREATE TABLE `Outbox`
    (`msg_id` `user_id`, `recipient`, `msg_body`, `date`);

INSERT INTO `Outbox`
    (`msg_id` `user_id`, `recipient`, `msg_body`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 100177, 22, `Hey buddy how are you?`, 1570319592),
    (2, 100423, 22, `Want to go swimming today?`, 1580319895),
    (3, 22, 100423, `Dinner is ready!`, 1510319492),
        (4, 4117, 22, `Who are you calling a twerp?`, 1520319772);


SELECT users AS usr, MAX(msg_id) 
FROM 
( SELECT user_id AS users, msg_id 
  FROM outbox 
  WHERE recipient = 22 
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT recipient AS users, msg_id 
FROM outbox 
WHERE user_id = 22 
GROUP BY users ) 
AS t GROUP BY usr DESC
```

Here is the last query I tried before giving up and begging for help here.

This query appears to provide the correct user_ids, however the results are sorted by the actual user_ids, so therefore if your very first member sends you a message, they will be shown underneath all of the others users even if you chatted with them the most recent.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! I know that there are several similar questions on here but I was unable to turn any similar examples into a working query of my own. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So you want each user you chatted shown only once? Then you can take the latest message for each user:

```
SELECT id, msg_id
FROM (
  SELECT user_id AS id, max(msg_id) as msg_id
  FROM Outbox 
  WHERE recipient = 22 
  GROUP BY user_id
  UNION 
  SELECT recipient, max(msg_id)
  FROM Outbox 
  WHERE user_id = 22
  GROUP BY recipient
) as q
ORDER BY msg_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET @userId = 22;
SELECT 
  MAX(msg_id) AS last_msg_id,
  IF (user_id = @userId, recipient, user_id) AS other_id 
FROM Outbox 
WHERE user_id = @userId OR recipient = @userId
GROUP BY other_id 
ORDER BY last_msg_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This will give order based on date, most recently communicated first:   SELECT 
     MAX(date) AS last_msg_date,
        IF (user_id = 22, recipient, user_id) AS other_user_id 
    FROM Outbox 
    WHERE user_id = 22 OR recipient = 22
    GROUP BY other_user_id 
    ORDER BY last_msg_date DESC
    LIMIT 10;